# How to test a static Java Web Service

Tags: java

can someone please suggest the best way to test this webservice? It does not get its data from a db, instead it generates its own data.

My problem is how to get hold of that data in my test.

```
@Path("/api/grid/accounts")
public class GridAccountService {

   private List<GridAccount> accountList = new ArrayList<GridAccount>(); // contains the statically created data

   public GridAccountService() {
      generateAccounts(500);  // creates a collection of objects      
   }

   public List<GridAccount> getAccountList() { // this does not work! Causes a CANNOT FIND SYMBOL error in the test
      return accountList;
   }

   private void generateAccounts(int max) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {                
            accountList.add(new GridAccount("Account" + count)); // other props removed for simplicity!
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public PaginationObject getAccounts(@QueryParam("crit") Criteria crit) {
        List<GridAccount> filteredAccountList = filter(accountListWithDetails, crit); // filter the list of generated accounts according to the criteria entered by the user
        PaginationObject obj = new PaginationObject(); // return this object
        obj.setData(filteredAccountList);
        obj.setTotal(filteredAccountList.size());            
        return obj;  
    }
}

private List<GridAccount> filter(List<GridAccount> accountList, Criteria criteria) {

   // First calls a method to translate the incoming criteria into predicates that can be understood by org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;     
   Predicate predicate = translate(criteria);
   // next calls apache's CollectionUtils to filter the list according to the predicate
   return CollectionUtils.filter(accountList, predicate);
}
```

My proposed jUnit test:

```
public class GridAccountServiceTest {
   @Test
   public void testGetAccounts() {
      /*
       This successfully calls the service's constructor that creates the data but how do I get hold of it?
      */
      GridAccountService service = new GridAccountService();
      /*
       I can define a getter in the service to get the collection
       but when I do this, it throws a CANNOT FIND SYMBOL error
      */
      List<GridAcccount> data = service.getAccountList(); 
   }

}
```

This is the CANNOT FIND SYMBOL ERROR from the compiler:

```
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute   goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default- testCom
pile) on project demo-services: Compilation failure
C:\ws\html5-framework-build\demo\demo-services\src\test\java\com\sungard\ui\demo   \resource\service\grid\GridAccountServiceTest.java:[59,12] error: cannot   find symbol

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
  uncher.java:409)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
  352)
   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException:    Compilation failure
   C:\ws\html5-framework-build\demo\demo-   services\src\test\java\com\sungard\ui\demo     \resource\service\grid\GridAccountServiceTest.java:[59,12] error: cannot      find symbol

   at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompiler
   Mojo.java:729)
   at org.apache.maven.plugin.TestCompilerMojo.execute(TestCompilerMojo.jav
   a:161)
   at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
   BuildPluginManager.java:101)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
   .java:209)
   ... 19 more
```

Comment: When asking about a compilation proble, paste the complete and exact error message, and show us the code causing it. We can't tell why unknown code causes an unknown error.

Comment: I'v updated the question with the stacktrace.

Comment: So, what is the line 59 of GridAccountServiceTest.java? If it's the line `List<GridAcccount> data = service.getAccountList(); `, where is the definition of the method `getAccountList()`you're calling?

Comment: Yes it is failing on List<GridAcccount> data = service.getAccountList(); I didn't put that line into the service but in my comment in the test I tried to make it clear that's what is causing the error.

Comment: So, you're calling a method getAccountList() on the service, but there is no such method in the class GridAccountService. What do you expect?

Comment: I'm sorry. I haven't made myself clear. I didn't put the method in the service in my stackoverflow question just to keep things simple. I will put it in now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question really is what behavior do you want to check?

If you want to check that the web service works you will probably need to start the webserver and use [HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net) or similar to make requests. You can then verify the content of the responses.

If you want to check the accounts static data are generated correctly, I would suggest you generate them outside of the service and pass them in via the constructor or some other means (e.g. via a setter or if necessary using a singleton). You can then check the generated data without having to refer to the service at all.

Alternatively, a much more hacky solution that would fix your immediate problem would be to make the (currently private) `accountList` field `public`. Then you can access that field directly from the test (after you have constructed the service) with `service.accountList`.

The compiler error 'symbol not found' would normally be picked up by an IDE and it would highlight exactly what the problem is. If you're not using an IDE, you might consider installing Eclipse or IntelliJ.

Comment: Hi aetheria, thanks for your very useful comments. What you say makes sense but even though I change the collection to public, it still throws the Cannot Find Symbol error. There must be something else going somewhere, I will follow your suggestion and use a java IDE (currently using Webstorm for javascript!!!)